# Using Shorcodes in Sharing Preview and Notifications Title from Post Title

Tags: php, date, wordpress-shortcode

I used some do_shortcode functions to work shortcode in post title and description. but i am unable to use shortcode in notification post title or sharing preview title. Here you can see my sample posts.

I want to add automatic date in my WordPress posts and posts title. I used Following codes to adding current date in WordPress posts.

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'do_shortcode' ); // activate shortcode in Yoast Title
add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'do_shortcode' ); // activate shortcode in Yoast Meta Description
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' ); // activate shortcode in WP Title

add_shortcode( 'current_date', 'mth_footer_date2' );
function mth_footer_date2() {
    ob_start();
   echo date("l, jS F Y");
   return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Above code is working fine.. but I unable to see date in Sharing preview or Notification Title. Kindly provide solution.

On my competitor's website, I seen that they also adding current date using shortcode. They use another code to done this. on those website, date appearing in both sharing preview and notifications. But, when I used that, I getting some errors. Here is that code.

```
function wpb_date_today($atts, $content = null) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'format' => ''
    ), $atts ) ); 
 
if ($atts['format'] == '') {
$date_time .= date(get_option('date_format')); 
}  else { 
$date_time .= date($atts['format']); 
} 
return $date_time;
} 
add_shortcode('date-today','wpb_date_today');
```

They use `[date-today]` to represent current date everywhere.